# moss library view

Tags: sharepoint-2007

My question is can display in moss library view,
 Only new items ,only items that are
 New

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a filter to the view, but how "New" is "New"?

http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/14/filter-list-view-by-current-week/

eg: Created today:

```
Created equals [Today]
```

**UPDATE**

By default the New! items are ones created int the last 24 hrs

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;825510&Product=spts

So follow the instructions in the link for creating a calculate column called "No of Days Old", and then set the filter on that to be "equal to or less than one"

Comment: i need only the item have ,green !new next to them